# WordPress wp_query sort by category and then by date

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting

I'm working on creating a custom page_template, where a list of projects are displayed and limited to show 5 projects per page. Each project post has a category of **projects**, and per my client's request they would want the ability to pin (feature) at least 2 projects to the top of the list.

Currently on the home page I have already configured it, so when the client want's to feature a project, all they have to do is to add a **feature** category to the post.

The issue I'm encountering, on the projects page, is that I cannot figure out how to sort the projects, so that the **feature** projects show up first and are sorted by their date, and then the rest of the projects are sorted by date. Any help will be greatly appreciated, and if I need to add any additional details, let me know.

Within my **projects.php** file

```
$paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$projectsArgs = array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => 5,
  'paged' => $paged,
  //'orderby' => array( 'taxonomy' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'ASC' ),
  'tax_query' => array(
                   array(
                     'taxonomy' => 'category',
                     'field'    => 'slug',
                     'terms'    => 'projects',
                   ),
               ),
  );

  $query = new WP_Query($projectsArgs);

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
      $query->the_post();
      echo '<article>
        <h5>' .get_the_title(). '</h5>
      </article>';
    }

    if ($query->max_num_pages > 1) {
      echo '<nav class="prev-next-posts">
              <div class="prev-posts-link">
                '. get_next_posts_link( 'Previous', $query->max_num_pages ). '
              </div>
              <div class="next-posts-link">
                '. get_previous_posts_link( 'Next' ).'
              </div>
            </nav>';

      wp_reset_postdata();
    }
  }
  else {
    echo '<article>';
      echo '<h1>Sorry...</h1>';
      echo '<p>' . _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.') . '</p>';
    echo '</article>';
  }
```